# Live streaming using YouTube on iOS

Tags: ios, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api, ytplayerview

I've successfully streamed *normal* YouTube videos on iOS using the [iOS YouTube helper](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper), but live stream does not seem to work.

I am not sure whether live streaming is even supported, but I could not find it in their docs.

Any idea how to make it work on iOS (without breaching ToS)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The playback of YouTube Live Events is supported by the `YTPlayerView` iOS helper classes.  The player will treat the Live Event video just like a regular YouTube video (as the iFrame player should), and your video should play back no problem with the "Live Broadcast" message replacing the scrubber of the player like so:

[image: Live Broadcast]

The only difference I have noticed is that the video will return an "auto" quality value.  I have submitted a patch to handle this case which has been merged in to the official repo [here](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/pull/56).